# How do you view ipv6 websites through browser?

Tags: ipv6

When I had Apache installed and running, I could type in "127.0.0.1" or the inet address I got from ifconfig, and I would be connected to my server.

However, if I type in "http://[::1/128]" in my address bar, I just get a Google search. How do I connect to websites from my browser with an ipv6 address?

In case it is relevant I use chrome with PinguyOS.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try without the `http://` and without the `/128`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The netmask is not part of the address. The scheme is optional if it's HTTP, and the port is optional if it's the default for the scheme. Otherwise, everything else applies as normal.

[image: Fedora Test Page on ::1]

Comment: The unnecessary netmask is the important part of the answer. It's not allowed in URLs since it wouldn't make sense to TCP connect to a network, only to a host, after all. (In other words, it's always a /128.)